# Laravel unit testing calling a method that calls that database

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mocking, faker

I have been trying to set up a unit test that calls a method where the database is called.  I have looked up mocking and faker and am confused about what to do.

In my test I call

```
Logic::lookForClassificationException($exception_array, $content);
```

In my method there is a call to my ClassificationException model

```
$exceptions = ClassificationException::select('exception')->get();
```

I am confused about how to set up a mock for this. ClassificationException is a table that has an id,  exception, previous_word, and after_word.

How do I mock or fake the setup?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do tests using DB is to setup an in memory sqlite database for tests like so:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

protected function setUpDatabase()
{
    $database = new DB;

    $database->addConnection(['driver' => 'sqlite', 'database' => ':memory:']);
    $database->bootEloquent();
    $database->setAsGlobal();
}
```

Then, call this function in your `setUp` method of the test class.

This is just one of many possible ways and may not suit your needs. Another way would be to setup a separate database for tests and [use a separate .env for tests](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/environment-specific-variables-in-laravels-testing-environment/)

In my experience, tests break down when you try to mock Eloquent models